# How to take absolute value in math function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to minus the value of "f1" from "f2" it works fine. However i want it just once but when i click the submit more more button it reduces every time the value of f1 from f2. How can it be done only once. It works well when i put value instead of when i call it from script.

```
    <form name=bills>

<p><input type="text" name="f1" size="20">
<input type="text" name="f2" size="20" value="30"></p>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="cbs(this.form)" name="B1">

    <Script>
    function cbs(form)

    {
        form.f2.value = (([document.bills.f2.value] * 1) - (document.bills.f1.value * 1))
    }
```

pls help

Answer (score 1):

The absulute value in math function in JavaScript is Math.abs();

```
Math.abs(6-10) = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but to calculate absolute value use `Math.abs()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to only work once, you can have something like this:

```
hasBeenRun = false; //have this variable outside the function

if(!hasBeenRun) {
    hasBeenRun = true;
    //Run your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be asking how to only subtract f1 from f2 only once, no matter how many times the submit button is clicked. One way to do it would be to have a variable that tracks if the function has been called already, and don't do the calculation if it has. As for the title mentioning absolute value, this is called by `Math.abs(value)`

```
<Script>
var alreadyDone = false;
function cbs(form)
{
    if (alreadyDone) return;
    // this one takes the absolute value of each value and subtracts them
    form.f2.value = (Math.abs(document.bills.f2.value) - Math.abs(document.bills.f1.value));

    // this one takes the absolute value of the result of subtracting the two
    form.f2.value = (Math.abs(document.bills.f2.value - document.bills.f1.value));
    alreadyDone = true;
}
```

In order to get the function to be able to work again when the value of f1 changes, simply change the variable `alreadyDone` back to false when f1 changes

```
<input type="text" name="f1" onChange="alreadyDone=false;" size="20">
```

Comment: Thx john. It is working as u said. However i need that it should not change but when falue of F1 changes than it should work again for once.
Thx again John

Comment: @chandrabhushan, I edited my answer to show how to make the function work again when F1 changes.